# Rails 5 - return records with an association count > 0 - PSQL/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, psql

I have 2 models; Category and Products and I want to return a list of all the categories that have at least 1 product assigned to them.

```
# app/models/category.rb
has_many :product_categories
has_many :products, through: :product_categories
```

Products is also set up with the associations through the join table and product category is set up with belongs_to for both product and category.

Im just trying to create a helper to list the categories and only want to return the ones that have products.

```
def category_list
   # Return categories here with at least 1 product
end
```

Comment: `Category.joins(:product_categories)` should give you a list of all categories with at least 1 `product_category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`counter_cache`](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3221) on `Category`, reset the model's counters, and then you can query `Category.where('product_count > ?', 0)`.